# Ionic 4 - Auto-scroll to a certain section based on date when user opens page

Tags: html, angular, firebase, ionic-framework, ionic4

I have a page that displays a list of ion-card elements with information read in from fire. Each element will display information about a sports fixture including date.

Some of these fixtures will be in the past and some will be in the future but when the user opens the page I want the page to automatically be opened displaying the ion-card where the date is closest to today's date. I hope that makes sense - I have no idea how to do it!

```
 <ion-content>

      <ion-card *ngFor="let match of matches"  tappable 
 routerLink="/../match-details-standard/{{match.id}}">

         <ion-card-content>    
             <ion-grid >
                 <ion-row>
                     <ion-col></ion-col>
                     <ion-col></ion-col>
                     <ion-col class="team" col-3>{{match?.team}}</ion-col>
                     <ion-col></ion-col>
                     <ion-col></ion-col>
                  </ion-row>

                 <!-- matchNotPlayed: If the match has been played then I 
 don't want to show the day which it was played -->
                 <ion-row *ngIf="match?.homeScore != ''; else 
 matchNotPlayed">
                     <ion-col></ion-col>
                     <ion-col></ion-col>
                     <ion-col col-3>{{match?.date.seconds * 1000 | date:'d 
 MMM yy' }}</ion-col>
                     <ion-col></ion-col>
                     <ion-col></ion-col>
                 </ion-row>
                 <ng-template #matchNotPlayed>
                     <ion-row> {{match?.date.seconds * 1000 | date:'EE d 
 MMM yy' }}</ion-row>
                 </ng-template> 
                 <!-- matchNotPlayed: End -->

                 <!-- noScoreReceived: If the match has been played and 
 scores updated then display scores else show 'v' between team names-->
                 <ion-row *ngIf="match?.homeScore != ''; else 
  noScoreReceived" border="solid">
                      <ion-col col-2>{{match?.home}}</ion-col>
                     <ion-col col-1 style="text-align: right"> 
 {{match?.homeScore}}</ion-col> 
                     <ion-col col-1> - </ion-col> 
                     <ion-col col-1 style="text-align: left"> 
 {{match?.awayScore}}</ion-col>
                     <ion-col col-2> {{match?.away}}</ion-col>
                  </ion-row>
                 <ng-template #noScoreReceived>
                     <ion-row>
                         <ion-col col-2>{{match?.home}}</ion-col> 
                         <ion-col col-1></ion-col>
                         <ion-col col-1> v </ion-col>
                         <ion-col col-1></ion-col>
                         <ion-col col-2> {{match?.away}}</ion-col>
                      </ion-row>
                  </ng-template> 
                 <!-- noScoreReceived -->

                 <ion-row> {{match?.date.seconds * 1000 | date:'h:mm a' }} 
 </ion-row>
              </ion-grid>    
          </ion-card-content>
     </ion-card>

  </ion-content>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to figure out on what position (y coördinate) this ion-card with the newest date is.
You can do this based on which position this card is in your array and how high one item would be when it's displayed.
With that information you can auto-scroll to a certain point with `scrollToPoint`

For more info see https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/content#scrollToPoint

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Content } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({...})
export class MyPage{
  @ViewChild(Content) content: Content;

  scrollToTop() {
    var x, y
    // Calculate y
    this.content.scrollToPoint(x,y);
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure it is possible to get the Y coordinate for this ion-card as I won't know how many cards there are - unless there is a specific method that returns the Y coordinate

Comment: Then try giving each card a unique id and use 'let y = document.getElementById(elementId).offsetTop;'